# How exactly do I link 2 blocks using the hash of the previous block?

Tags: c++, pointers, hash, blockchain

I'm new to Blockchain, and want to implement a basic Blockchain in C++ on my own. I was making an analogy to a linked list, and was wondering, how exactly do I link the block chains together using hashes instead of pointers?

Consider this snippet of Linked List implementation in C++:

```
struct node
    {
        node *prev;
        string data;
    }

main()
{
    node *first=new node;
    node *second=new node;
    second->prev=first;
}
```

Now consider this barebones block structure of a blockchain:

```
class block
    {
        string hash;
        string prev_hash;
        string data;

        public:
        string calc_hash();
    }

main()                       
{
    block genesis;
    genesis.data="name,gender,age";
    genesis.hash=calc_hash(data);
    genesis.prev_hash=0000;
    block second;
    second.data="name,gender,age";
    second.hash=calc_hash(data);
    second.prev_hash=genesis.hash;
}
```

Now, how exactly do I link those blocks together using hashes instead of pointers? Or is it just supposed to be implemented like a linked list with pointers but with some function for validating the integrity of the blocks?

Answer (score 2):

The block contains a header and some data (usually transactions). The only part that is used to calculate the hash is the block header.

The block header contains the following:

### Block Header

{version 4B} {previous block hash 32B} {merkle root hash 32B} {time 4B} {bits 4B} {nonce 4B}

```
version (4 Bytes) - Block format version.
previous block hash (32 Bytes) - The hash of the preceding block. This is important to include in the header because the hash of the block is calculated from the header, and thus depends on the value of the previous block, linking each new block to the last. This is the link in the chain of the blockchain.
merkle root hash (32 Bytes) - The hash of the merkle tree root of all transactions in the block. If any transaction is changed, removed, or reordered, it will change the merkle root hash. This is what locks all of the transactions in the block.
time (4 Bytes) - Timestamp in Unix Time (seconds). Since the clocks of each node around the world is not guaranteed to be synchronized, this is just required to be within of the rest of the network.
bits (4 Bytes) - Target hash value in Compact Format. The block hash must be equal to or less than this value in order to be considered valid.
nonce (4 Bytes) - Can be any 4 Byte value, and is continuously changed while mining until a valid block hash is found.
```

Comment: No, this is not what I was asking. Please see my updated description, it may help in understanding my question better.

Comment: `second.prev_hash=genesis.hash;` this is how you link them, you've already done it. You don't want to load all blocks into memory like a linked list, you wouldn't have enough memory. You would persist them in a database, for example, with their hash as an index. Then, before you add any new blocks to the database, you validate them by checking their data, header, and hash  for validity, including that the previous block hash exists and the data is valid (e.g. no double spends)

Comment: Okayy, got it now. Thanks a lot :)